# How often should I review my notes?

Tags: productivity

Many years ago I was studying with the Open University. During that time I bought a revision aid. The basic principle was that you wrote out all you knew about a topic immediately after learning it. The note pages were marked so that they could be referenced against a sort of calendar. The idea was that you read through your notes something like the next day, again a week later and again something like 4 weeks later.

I recall that the thinking was that the frequency set coincided with the way your brain moves stuff from short- to long-term memory.

I'm just about to start studying again and I wondered if anyone might know what the frequency for reviewing one's notes might have been.

Comment: Are you asking about what is a good revision frequency from a scientific perspective? Or are you asking about what revision history was used in the particular software that you used to use? If its about software, I imagine it would be important to know what the software was called.

Comment: I'm really asking about what a good revision frequency might be. As I said, I'm about to start studying again and would like to give myself the best chance of making a decent fist of it.

Comment: Although this question *is* about Academia and learning, Your question seems opinion-based to me. Learning habits differs from one to another. Some people learn fast, some other need more frequent revisions. There is no solid advice here.

Comment: Are you looking for an answer based on personal experience, or research with supporting citation? If you're mainly interested in the latter, you should [edit] the question to say so, and also add the [tag:reference-request] tag.

Comment: @ff524, I'm looking for an answer based on personal experience. As I've said, I'm about to start studying again and am looking for a as much of a leg up as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several algorithms for scheduled repetition of information on flash cards. It's possible that the software you liked uses one of these. This Wikipedia article on [spaced repetiton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition) discusses Pimsleur's graduated-interval recall and Leitner system, among others. This isn't the easiest topic to search for, but the Wikipedia article calls it "spaced repetition", and includes a list of alternative names. That should help you do further research.